# Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I would like to parse JSON array data with jquery ajax with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var result;
    function jsonparser1() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://10.211.2.219:8080/SampleWebService/sample.do",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (xml) {
                alert(xml.data[0].city);
                result = xml.code;
                document.myform.result1.value = result;
            },
        });
    }        
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<p id="details"></p>
<form name="myform">
    <input type="button" name="clickme" value="Click here to show the first name" onclick=jsonparser1() />
    <input type="text" name="result1" readonly="true"/>        
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My JSON data is:

```
{"Data":   [{"Address":"chetpet","FirstName":"arulmani","Id":1,"LastName":"sathish","City":"chennai"},{"Address":"ramapuram","FirstName":"raj","Id":2,"LastName":"nagu","City":"chennai"},{"Address":"ramapuram","FirstName":"raj","Id":2,"LastName":"nagu","City":"chennai"},{"Address":"ramapuram","FirstName":"ramaraj","Id":3,"LastName":"rajesh","City":"chennai"},{"Address":"ramapuram","FirstName":"yendran","Id":3,"LastName":"sathi","City":"chennai"}],"Code":true}
```

But i am not getting any output...anybody please help out...

Comment: Maybe it's your backend who doesn't return anything. Post it!

Comment: Use JSON.parse to parse JSON data. in success: function(data) { var result = JSON.parse(data); document...value = result.Code; }

Comment: **I wrote an answer for this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)** – _the last one, supports https_

Answer (score 92, accepted):

### Concept explained

Are you trying do a cross-domain AJAX call? Meaning, your service is not hosted in your same web application path? Your web-service must support method injection in order to do JSONP.

Your code seems fine and it should work if your web services and your web application hosted in the same domain.

When you do a `$.ajax` with `dataType: 'jsonp'` meaning that jQuery is actually adding a new parameter to the query URL.

For instance, if your URL is `http://10.211.2.219:8080/SampleWebService/sample.do` then jQuery will add `?callback={some_random_dynamically_generated_method}`.

This method is more kind of a proxy actually attached in `window` object. This is nothing specific but does look something like this:

```
window.some_random_dynamically_generated_method = function(actualJsonpData) {
    //here actually has reference to the success function mentioned with $.ajax
    //so it just calls the success method like this: 
    successCallback(actualJsonData);
}
```

**Summary**

Your client code seems just fine. However, you have to modify your server-code to wrap your JSON data with a function name that passed with query string. i.e.

If you have reqested with query string

```
?callback=my_callback_method
```

then, your server must response data wrapped like this:

```
my_callback_method({your json serialized data});
```

Comment: **I wrote an answer for this question here:
[Loading cross domain html page with jQuery AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)** – _the last one, supports https_

Comment: @AbdulMunim: Is it possible to mention the json file in the url property of $.ajax? What are the file extensions supported in url property? is just anything returns with padded js callback?

Comment: Is that why I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in the console? The error has a link which once I click on shows me the JSON data.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the ajax-cross-origin plugin:
http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/

Just add the option crossOrigin: true

```
$.ajax({
    crossOrigin: true,
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: if I got that right it routes things through a third party proxy. convenient, but traffic through a server might defeat the original idea

Comment: I have added the same but everytime it gives a failed error. I am using jsonp data type.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON-data contains the property `Data`, but you're accessing `data`. It's case sensitive

```
function jsonparser1() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://10.211.2.219:8080/SampleWebService/sample.do",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (xml) {
            alert(xml.Data[0].City);
            result = xml.Code;
            document.myform.result1.value = result;
        },
    });
}
```

**EDIT** Also City and Code is in the wrong case. (Thanks @Christopher Kenney)

**EDIT2** It should also be json, and not jsonp (at least in this case)

**UPDATE** According to your latest comment, you should read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11736771/325836 by Abdul Munim

Comment: What happens if you try to browse directly to the URL?

Comment: And what errors do you get in the Error console of your browser?

Comment: Its showing there is unexpected token : in JSON data... but its the correct way of usind the arrays in JSON right???

Comment: @ChristopherKenney : Its showing error if i put datatype as 'json'. Its ok if i put it as 'jsonp'.

Comment: Errors if i use json instead of jsonp:  1)XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://10.211.2.219:8080/SampleWebService/sample.do. Origin http://localhost:3555 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
sample.do   2)GET http://10.211.2.219:8080/SampleWebService/sample.do undefined (undefined)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alert(xml.Data[0].City)
```

**Case sensitivly!**

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse  your xml with jquery json parse...i.e

```
  var parsed_json = $.parseJSON(xml);
```

Comment: Is that in the success function? Because I get an error in the console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` and it displays the error function alert, doesn't even hit the success function.

Answer (score 0):

alert(xml.data[0].city);

use xml.data["Data"][0].city instead

Answer (score 0):

use open public proxy YQL, hosted by Yahoo.  Handles XML and HTML

https://gist.github.com/rickdog/d66a03d1e1e5959aa9b68869807791d5