# get xml data from url using js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XmlHttpRequest error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

I have tried different ways to read xml data from url using js,ajax,jquery but there is no use.

The xml url is : http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-java?pshid=46484&ssty=2&cflg=r&jbd=nichehire.jobamatic.com&clip=183.82.97.123

I got error which looks like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load "http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-java?pshid=46484&ssty=2&cflg=r&jbd=nichehire.jobamatic.com&clip=183.82.97.123." Origin http://www.nichehire.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Do I need to add request headers while requesting the url.

if so how can I add request header while requesting,

Is there any procedure to follow for getting XML data from URL.

can some one Please try this URL with your code to read XML data and let me know if possible

i have tried below code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
url: "http://api.simplyhired.com/a/jobs-api/xml-v2/q-java?pshid=46484&ssty=2&cflg=r&jbd=nichehire.jobamatic.com&clip=183.82.97.123",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {
alert(xml);
}});
```

Comment: Try to google `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and press `I feel lucky`

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771