# AJAX request from Cordova app returns 'status=0'

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, post, cordova

I have a question. I am developing a cordova application for ios, and I try to make an AJAX request using jQuery. The external server is whitelisted in the cordova.plist (in fact I whitelisted * just to be sure). I am sure the function is correct since I can manually call it in chrome, and it returns the correct data.

It however returns the following header data when run in the application:
`{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}`

When `crossDomain` is changed to `false` it returns the following header data:
`{"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":404,"statusText":"error"}`

```
$.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: url,  
   data: request,  
   crossDomain:true,  
   success:  
       function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){  
           console.log('succes :S');  
           console.log(data);  
           console.log(textStatus);  
           console.log(jqXHR);  
       },  
    error:   
       function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){  
           console.log('fail :(');  
           console.log(data);  
           console.log(textStatus);  
           console.log(jqXHR);  
       }  
});
```

I hope someone can tell me whats wrong, because I tried everything I can think of.

EDIT: Thank you guys, but I figured out what the problem was. The project used to have encryption and there where still some remnants of the code present in the native classes. So it en- or decrypted some URLs. This topic can be closed now.

Comment: Does "whitelist" mean that the server sends the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header as `*`?

Comment: @devnull69 Whitelist means telling Cordova and the mobile OS you wish to make network requests the whitelisted domains. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_whitelist_index.md.html#Domain%20Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Is there any way for you to make sure that the request your app sends is making it to the server?

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question a while back, and provided methods to fix Mootools and jQuery (as well as a vanilla javascript method)

Here:
[PhoneGap ajax call fails everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964383/phonegap-ajax-call-fails-everytime/19498463#19498463)

Answer (score 0):

Use IP or Virtual DNS instead of localhost if you are using so.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to specify  dataType 'JSONP' like below

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

It's a solution to js crossdomain calls

see this post

[Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)

Comment: You'd also need to make sure to change the server response from `"{....}"` to `callback("{....}")`. But the OP didn't say anything about receiving JSON from the server

Comment: Thank you guys, but I figured out what the problem was. The project used to have encryption and there where still some remnants of the code present in the native classes. So it en- or decrypted some URLs. This topic can be closed now.

Answer (score -1):

Remove below meta tag from your HTML file :

https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

Hope this works!!!