# jQuery Ajax Request to get JSON data fires error event

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, request

I'm trying to make an ajax request to a Google API, to get JSON data of current exchange rate.

My code so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=de&q=1USD=?EUR"
}).done( function ( data ) {
    var obj = $.parseJSON( data )
    alert( data.rhs );
});
```

The link for the google api is http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=de&q=1USD=?EUR

my problem is that my code doesn't fire the `done` function.

I know there is missing something, maybe some params?

---

**UPDATE**

here is my new code that i've found somewhere:

```
    function forex(val, from, to, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q='+val+from+'%3D%3F'+to,
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'string',
            success: function(data) {
                var json = eval("(" + data+ ")"), output;
                if (typeof json == 'object' && json.rhs) {
                    output = json.rhs.match(/[0-9.\s]+/ig);
                    output = output[0] || false;
                } else {
                    output = data.match(/[0-9.\s]+/ig);
                    output = output[1] || false;
                }
                output = (output !== false) ? Number(output.replace(/\s/,'')) : output;
                callback(output);
            },
            error: function() {
                callback(false);
            }
        });
    }

    function output(data) {
        alert( data );
        $('#show_product_price_api').val(data);   
    }
```

but when i use this function :

```
forex(100, 'USD', 'EUR', output);
```

to fire the event, i get a "FALSE" callback

any idea why this error function is called ??

---

**UPDATE 2**

i think it's a cross domain issue, does anyone have any sugestions using jsonp ?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `ajax` even?

Comment: i did, but i got confused

Comment: `dataType:"json"` is missing.

Comment: using $.getJson might help

Comment: @Ace are you returning json form the url specified in ajax?

Comment: i think so, just give a look at the link abow

Answer (score 1):

Code is fine. 
Take a look at the http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=de&q=1USD=?EUR's response.

It is not a valid JSON string. so it will not go into the done.

Response is `{lhs: "1 US-Dollar",rhs: "0,767165324 Euro",error: "",icc: true}  It should be {"lhs": "1 US-Dollar","rhs": "0,767165324 Euro","error": "","icc": true}`.

**Edited:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=de&q=1USD=?EUR"
}).done( function ( data ) {
    data = data.replace(/([a-z0-9]+):/gi,"\"$1\":"));
    var obj = $.parseJSON( data )
    alert( data.rhs );
});
```

Comment: ok , there is a syntax error in row 4 ( double close bracked )

Comment: and i still get no alert :

Comment: can you alert the data before parsing to JSON and post it here. That ill help me to fix it.

Comment: Edit your question with the response what you have got from URL.

Comment: i dont get ANY response. the .ajax und .getJASON method fires an error each time.

Comment: This may be because of Cross browser issue. You could track the error using firefox's debugger. Better, u have to write ur own server script that sends req to google and return the response to ur ajax. Check how to do http request through PHP or whatever u use..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771

Comment: ty , but i've just did a custom php script that ajax is acually referencing now