# cross domain jquery get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I saw some examples of cross domain with ajax but it doesn't work.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var url = "http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=AssasNet&include_rts=1";

                $.get(url, function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    alert(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I try on chrome and the following error is given:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=AssasNet&include_rts=1. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: Where do you have that example from? It's not correct

Comment: You have to set up the external server specially to use cross-domain AJAX that way, which you can't do here. [Use JSON-P instead.](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/)

Comment: Also there is only the statement. Not an actual question. Just suggested "where's the bug"

Comment: Make sure you're not using chrome and locahost to test. It is a known issue that Chrome does not support cross domain requests on localhost

Comment: @JeremyBlalock: FWIW, that Twitter API doesn't support calls from `http://jsbin.com` either, so I suspect it just doesn't support CORS.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it was mainly for any future viewers of this question who are using a different API, etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can't use `$.get` because that does an ajax call, which will be cross-origin and thus blocked by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), and the Twitter API you're trying to access doesn't support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (or if it does, it doesn't allow either origin `null` or `http://jsbin.com`, which is the one I tried).

The API does support [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) (which is not a true ajax call), though, so just changing the `$.get` to an `$.ajax` specifying `JSONP` works:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/igivok/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/igivok/1/edit)

Comment: I tried this for "https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-10658066" but I just got error. Is your solution applicable to cross domain?

Comment: @Arya - Yes, ***if*** the API supports JSONP. Most don't.