# AJAX Request not working to fetch data from localhost:8080

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, spring-boot

I am trying to fetch data from localhost:8080 using the following code

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html,body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <!--<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKqvfwhEajjWqM0t8jE2Mg7eacHcbzySc&callback=initMap"></script>--> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function readfile(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://localhost:8080/locations",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                type:'GET',
                success: function(result){
                window.alert("HI");
                console.log(result);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    window.alert(jqXHR.status);
                },
                timeout:48000,
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload= "readfile()"></body>
</html>
```

Since this is a CORS request, I have installed a Allow Control Access plugin in Google Chrome. The data that is displayed in localhost:8080/locations is as follows

```
[{"latitude":"13.0000","longitude":"27.0000"},`{"latitude":"16.000","longitude":"50.000"},{"latitude":"13.0000","longitude":"27.0000"},{"latitude":"16.0000","longitude":"29.0000"}]
```

The REST API has been written using Springboot and it is making a GET request which results in the above data at the localhost:8080/locations. The error handle gets triggered when opening index.html but with a status 200 and nothing is displayed.

Is there a problem with my AJAX code and how can I solve it and fetch the JSON displayed in localhost on the webpage aand process it.

**EDIT**

datatype:json and not jsonp. There were many other Stackoverflow articles which said when making a CORS request jsonp needs to be used and not json. Refer [cross domain jquery get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369577/cross-domain-jquery-get) . Can someone explain what exactly is happening ?

Comment: You set a `dataType: 'jsonp'`, but describe as if you would be getting plain JSON. So what is it?

Comment: I think url should be relative(uri) rather complete url. `type: "GET",
    url: "/locations",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType:'jsonp',`, try this inside your ajax function.

Comment: Maybe change `dataType: 'jsonp'` to `dataType: 'json'`. To know more about the difference - [Read here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114013014/http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html)

Comment: changing 'jsonp' to 'json' solved it .

Comment: Ok. to know more about the difference, go through this [brilliant article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160114013014/http://json-jsonp-tutorial.craic.com/index.html)