# ajax request to get aliexpress home page

Tags: jquery, ajax, aliexpress

two days trying to reach **aliexpress.com** homepage with simple ajax request with no luck, it's not easy as i expect .

all errors around access policy and origin issues.

can any body give me jquery ajax code to do that.

**MY CODE**

```
  function setHeader(xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    }
    //url: 'https://www.aliexpress.com',

    function getHomePage() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.aliexpress.com',
            type: 'GET',
            callback: '?',
            data: '',
            datatype: 'text/html',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            error: function () { alert('Failed!'); },
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });

    } //end getHomePage
```

**Call:**

```
getHomePage();
```

**Errors:**
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of making the request? There's a reason why the CORS policy is in place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cross domain jquery get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369577/cross-domain-jquery-get)

Comment: @Boaz The project is an intermediary shop for collecting products from several stores.

Comment: @Boaz i tried several solutions about CORS but nothing of these working in my case .

Comment: Look for an existing API to AliExpress. Scraping is not a viable solution in most cases.

Comment: _“i tried several solutions about CORS but nothing of these working in my case”_ - well the main reason for that is likely that you simply have not understood how CORS works ... _You_ can not allow this request from your end, `www.aliexpress.com` is the one that would have to allow it.

Comment: @CBroe i know that is aliexpress can allow or not, but in simple way i want to simulate browser request .

Comment: Not _can_ allow, __must__ allow. Without the remote site giving consent, you can not make this client-side cross-domain request. (If you only need this for testing purposes, then you can get yourself a browser extension that overwrites this, but that will of course only work for you, not for other people visiting your site. If you need it for the latter as well, then you have to proxy the request via your own domain, like mukama suggested in their answer.)

Comment: Many thanks @CBroe i'll try with mukama suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, jQuery alone can't help. You have to take the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) for JavaScript into account. You may want to consider to creating a proxy script at your domain.

The proxy would look something like this: /get_ali_express.php

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents("https://www.aliexpress.com");
?>
```

And the js: some where in say, /index.html

```
<script>
    function getHomePage() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/get_ali_express.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            error: function () { alert('Failed!'); }
        });
    } 
</script>
```