# WCF sending JSON, object in method always null

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf

I want to send JSON data to my WCF Service, but in the Service there is my object always null. I have read so many articles but I can't solve my problem.

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/POST/PersonPost", Method = "POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 public Person InsertPerson(Person per)
 {   Debug.WriteLine("InsertPerson");
     if (per == null)
    {
       return new Person("2", "null");
    }

    Debug.WriteLine("POST:[PersonId = {0} PersonName = {1}]", per.Id, per.Name);
        return new Person("1", "InsertPerson");
  }

[DataContract]
    public class Person
    {

        public Person(string id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]            
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
            return json.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and here my jQuery:

```
var person = {};
                person.Id = "abc123";
                person.Name = "aaaa";
                var per = {};
                per.per = person;

                var param = JSON.stringify(per);


                //param =   "{"per":{"Id":"abc123","Name":"aaaa"}}"

                $.support.cors = true;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: param,
                    dataType: "json",
                    processData: false,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    url: "http://localhost:59291/Person/POST/PersonPost",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Post erfolgreich: ");

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Fehler Post: Status " + xhr.status + " AntwortText " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

What is there wrong? Why is my parameter per in the insertPerson method always null.

Comment: Is your service and web site running in the same domain? If not it will be because of this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. You cannot send requests across domains. The browser won't let you. Well not without configuration..

Comment: no they running on two different places, but I can't change this. The method on the server side is starting, the parameter is only null. Is there no way?

Comment: is my configuration therefore correct, I mean is the json compatible with my service

Comment: Well your first problem is this will not work across domains....at all(full stop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry my english, this work for me:

```
var LstPerson = new Array();
var person = {};

person.Id = 1
person.name = 'abc'

LstPerson.push(person)

var param = JSON.stringify(LstPerson);
```

send only [{"id": "1", "name": "abc"}]  from JS, and WCF REST definition:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, 
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Person InsertPerson(List<Person> per)
```

Comment: Jesus Torres, you are the Man!!!
Thank you merry much, this code is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because the `DataMember`s are `id` and `name` and not `Id` and `Name`. You need to modify the following code:

```
person.Id = "abc123";
person.Name = "aaaa";
var per = {};
per.per = person;
```

to

```
person.id = "abc123";
person.name = "aaaa";
var per = {};
per.per = person;
```

Comment: I assumed Same Origin. See other answers for the other reason this may not be working. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your web site is breaking the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Heres [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Your setting [crossDomain](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `true`, but this is only compatible with jsonp, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var person = {};
person.id = "1";
person.name = "abc";
var param = JSON.stringify(person);
```

One of the reasons, you are receiving your request object as null because, the method is expecting an object of type Person. This in JSON is as follows according to your definition of Person.

```
{"id": "1", "name": "abc"}
```

This is because there is nothing like per inside Person.

```
Person person = New Person("1", "abc");
person.per //There is nothing defined as per inside person.
```