# Json posted array has null values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I have the following json object, sorry for the image;

[image]

The jquery code I have looks like this;

```
var data = {
    table: table,
    favour: $("[name='radFavour']:checked").val(),
    data: jsonObj
};

$.ajax({
    url: appDomain + "/Compare/Ajax_Update",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: data
});
```

The c# code looks like;

```
[HttpPost]
public void Ajax_Update(CompareFVM fvm)
{
}
```

The FVM contains a string for table and for favour and the data for those two properties comes through.

For "data" I have the following in the FVM;

```
public List<CompareItem> data { get; set; }
```

And the item;

```
public class CompareItem
{
    public int prodId { get; set; }
    public int stageId { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string property { get; set; }
}
```

The List has the correct amount of elements in it, in this case two, but each of them has nulls set.

So the data I am posting back is not coming through for the array elements but it is for the single fields.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried List, IEnumerable and an Array.  I have also tried JSON.stringify.  Nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while ajax calling, pass the objectname as 'fvm'(name should be matching with the C# code parameter). also, please check passing json abject using JSON.stringify(data).

```
    var fvm = {
        table: table,
        favour: $("[name='radFavour']:checked").val(),
        data: jsonObj
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: appDomain + "/Compare/Ajax_Update",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(fvm)
    });
```

Comment: All the names match that that is being passed.  Like I said, I am passing two objects back in "data".  At the C# end, my FVM.data list has two objects.  Both contain defaults and not the actual data.  So it knows there are two objects, but the mapping is screwing up.

Comment: And I have already tried stringify and that didn't work either.

Comment: i think [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771) can help you

Comment: "Are you trying do a cross-domain AJAX call? Meaning, your service is not hosted in your same web application path? Your web-service must support method injection in order to do JSONP" - then this can help you

Comment: No there is no cors issue here.

Comment: not sure why you are facing the issue, I tried and its working for me.. the object is having simple structure. code: 

    var composite = {
        BoolValue: true,
        StringValue: "Hello "
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(composite),
        datatype: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

Just basing off what similar things I've done in the past, I'd structure your code like so:

```
// if your C# is
public void Ajax_Update(CompareFVM fvm) {
}

// then your ajax call should be along the lines of
$.ajax({
    data : {
        'data' : [
            { /* compareItem */ },
            { /* compareItem */ },
            // ...
        ]         
    }
})
```

The thing being, your C# endpoint is expecting an object, so you should give it a JSON object.

If your C# class is

```
public class CompareFVM {
    public IList<CompareItem> data { get;set; }
}
```

then your corresponding JSON should be:

```
{ 'data' : [] }
```

where `.data` would be an array of `CompareItem` objects.

e.g.

```
{ 
    'data' : [
        {'prodId':'3175','stageId':'19045','value':'TUE','property':'despatchDay'},
        {'prodId':'3175','stageId':'19045','value':'TUE','property':'despatchDay'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: i've tried hardcodeing the array data like you have here and the array has the correct element count but the data is empty