# JSON Object Empty On POST to C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

jQuery:

```
$('#test').click(function () {

    var obj = new Object();
    var childObj = new Object();

    childObj.name = 'dominic';
    childObj.age = 22;

    obj.children = new Object ({ child : childObj });

    console.log(obj);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Test")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: obj,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            //console.log(msg.status);
        }
    });

});
```

C# (MVC 4):

```
public JsonResult Test(testObj obj)
{
    foreach (childObj child in obj.children)
    {
        Debug.Print(child.name);
        Debug.Print(child.age);
    }

    return Json(null);
}

public class testObj
{
    public List<childObj> children { get; set; }
}

public class childObj
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

When I debug, `obj` has a `children` property, but it is always null...  In my browser console, it is not null...

Comment: try replacing `obj.children = new Object ({ child : childObj });` by `obj.children = [{ child : childObj }];`

Comment: What do you see with [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/)? What do you see with [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)?

Comment: Try sending with JSON.stringify(jsonObj), as my answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16954125/json-posted-array-has-null-values/16954189?noredirect=1#comment24483646_16954189)

Comment: You don't have to use `new Object`; you can just use `{}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First I would recommend you sending complex objects from the client to the server as JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Test")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        //console.log(msg.status);
    }
});
```

Things to notice:

1. `contentType: 'application/json'`
2. `data: JSON.stringify(obj)`

Also your `children` property on the client must be an array, not a property:

```
var obj = {};
var childObj = {};

childObj.name = 'dominic';
childObj.age = 22;

obj.children = [];
obj.children.push(childObj);
```

or simply:

```
var obj = {
    children: [
        { name: 'dominic', age: 22 }
    ]
};
```

Another remark: On the server your Age property is defined as string whereas on the client you are passing it as integer (`age: 22`) which is inconsistent. In addition to that you don't need to put all your C# properties in lowercase. That's just horrible. The JavaScriptSerializer is intelligent enough to respect the standard C# naming convention:

```
public class TestObj
{
    public List<ChildObj> Children { get; set; }
}

public class ChildObj
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The JavaScript was the problem; but your notes about C# are helpful, too.

Comment: As you said above about the Content Type in the Ajaxify piece, `contentType: 'application/json'` . I saw in many places `charset = UTF-8`. Why do we add this in the content type ?

Comment: @Pankaj content-type is only needed if you are receiving data back and you want to specify the type of data that is.  The default is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` as per http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/