# Need help in passing value form JS to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have some problem with passing value from javascript file to php file.
I make some calculations in JS, and after that i passing it to php.
This is a code of JS:

```
var price=100;// for example

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SecureRide.php",
            data: { calculatedPrice: price }
        });
```

And this is a code of PHP:

```
<?php 
session_name("ridePrice");
session_start();

$_SESSION["calculatedPrice"]=$_POST["calculatedPrice"];
echo $_SESSION["calculatedPrice"];
```

?>

So what i do is a simple Ajax function that passes the value to php, very simple, but doesn't work!
When I do echo function there's nothing there.
Maybe there are another way to solve it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Try checking your web developer tools to see if the ajax is posting and what response you are getting.

Comment: Do you have jQuery lib included?

Comment: Also, specify the contentType for the $.ajax function. By default it sends it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. You need to use `application/json` or something of the like.

Comment: I've done it already, ajax is posting and I do get the exact value i need, And yes, Jquery included

Comment: Where do you expect output to occur here and where are you looking for it exactly?

Comment: is secureRide.php an example or is maybe the page on another domani? in this case you'll have to use jsonp for the request

Comment: Do you firebug installed? Can you see the request going out and the response coming back?

Comment: secureRide.php in not example, it's a real page i use, it's in the same domain, in the same folder.How i can do it with jsonp? may be it will help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery . Last time i had a problem like yours this solved everything.

Comment: do `var_dump($_SESSION);` what it gives ?

Answer (score 1):

Note : if you are put your ajax code in function and than call function from the "$(document).ready(function(){" then your code run perfectly

I write code in your .js  file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
functionName(price);
});

function functionName(price){

 $.ajax({

  url: 'SecureRide.php', 
  data:{calculatedPrice: price},
  type: 'POST',
     success:function(data)
     {
      alert(data);           
     }, 
     error:function(data) 
     { 
     alert("mistake in your code");
     } 
   }) 
 }
```

And Code For PHP file for get .JS File Data

```
if(isset($_POST['calculatedPrice']) && !empty($_POST['calculatedPrice'])) 
  {
  $calculatedPrice1=$_POST['calculatedPrice'];
  }
```