# How to get web service data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have token value in a URL like `http://example.com/api.php?action=token`
I need to consume this URL data which is a random string, I'm trying with following code:

```
var jqxhr = $.get("http://example.com/api.php?action=token", function() {
    alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
});

// Perform other work here ...

// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() {
    alert( "second finished" );
});
```

Using [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

While trying to load, it's showing an error. I'm just stuck with it, how to get the data?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to request? Is it Json?

Comment: now getting "error" as in alert and GET status is failed

Comment: Is the service on your own domain? If not, you'll need to do either a CORS or JSONP request, and both of those need to be enabled on the server.

Comment: to access data you need to add a parameter on your callbacks e.g. `.done(function(data) {`

Comment: callback is not working

Comment: @sukanta what is the error you get? it works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/djEn7/ if you are not doing cross domain call

Comment: @Andy i am calling another server, i mean another domain

Comment: @sukanta cross domain call is not allowed by the browser.... check out jsonp or proxy with server side code

Comment: so what's the solution here if i want to get this data via javascript ?

Comment: now data is in JSON format but not getting it, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross domain calls are restricted by the browser so some solutions are,

1.Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) or jsonp, but you will require  to have access to the server you are calling and configure that *(many examples online e.g. [How to make cross domain request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request))*

2.server side proxy - create simple server side code e.g. *php* page that you will call form js and place code in php that calls the targeted cross domain server and return the results to your js. e.g. [AJAX cross domain call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $.ajax({
              url:"http://example.com/api.php?action=token",
              type: "GET",
              success: function (data) {
                   alert(data)
              }
           });
```

Comment: this might be a cross domain issue

Comment: for cross domain you should use the jsonp

Comment: for cross domain you check my below post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282846/display-json-data-using-jquery/21283556?noredirect=1#comment32073894_21283556

Comment: so if i dont get the data in json format i cant receive this in clinet end with this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $.ajax({
              url:"http://example.com/api.php?action=token",
              type: "POST",           //try this
              success: function (data) {
                   alert(data)
              }
           });
```