# How to get a CSV file with an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

I have this small `Ajax` function that is suppose to grab an online `CSV` file but it keeps failing with this error:

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE:
    request.send();                  csonv.js (line 101)
```

The function in question looks like this:

```
 var ajax = function(url) {
        request = new(window.ActiveXObject || XMLHttpRequest)("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        request.open("GET", url, 0);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send();
        return request.responseText;
```

I am attempting to use [csonv.js](https://github.com/archan937/csonv.js) to grab a CSV file from the internet and convert it to `JSON`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the web server you're contacting have a MIME type entry for .csv files? Can you download the file by typing its URL in a browser?

Comment: Is the URL in your domain?

Comment: I am able to download the file in my browser. It is a public file on a public website. I also have a Java function that successfully attains it using `URL,` `URLConnection,` `InputStreamReader,` and `BufferedReader.`

Comment: I see a bunch of issues here, although I'm not sure if they would cause your problem.  1.  You are using the xmlhttp object if it's available.  You should reverse this and only use it if xmlhttprequest is not available.  2. Why are you not doing this asynchronously?  3. Why are you setting content-type to x-www-form-urlencoded when you aren't posting data to a form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request