# Making an ajax request from a different domain

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

This question has probably been answered before but I haven't been able to find a suitable answer.

I'm using asp.net web forms and am wanting to make a jquery Ajax request from one site on a particular domain to another site on another domain. The Ajax request is to a web method on an aspx page.

As expected I am having problems with CORS. My question is are you able to make an Ajax call to a web method on an aspx page from a different domain? If so any advice or links to resources would be very grateful.

Thanks David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got several options. First, you can use CORS (http://enable-cors.org/) but only if you've got access to the application on the target server.

Alternatively, you can use JSONP (but again, the server must support it): http://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/.

The last thing that comes into my mind would be using your server as a proxy: call a web service on your server which calls the remote server. This should work as server-to-server communication is not restricted by same origin policy (it's a browser feature).

Also, take a look at this thread: [How to make cross domain request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request)

Answer (score 0):

As a security measure, AJAX does not allow you to make requests to other domains.

Comment: You can use cross domain ajax request BUT server needs to allow it