# How do I import the HTML from website 1 to populate input fields in website 2?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, import

I have a form on website 2 that I need to populate with data on website 1. The code I have so far is:

```
function fillOutForm () {
document.getElementById('input1').value="innerHTMLFromWebsite2";
}
```

How do I import the HTML from website 2 and insert it into the "innerHTMLFromWebsite2" section of the above code?

Also to note the 2 websites are on different domains. Think website1 is www.mycompany.com and website2 is www.tripadvisor.com.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can open url in iframe and then you can get complete html by javascript: document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because of the same-origin policy  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

You can disable that policy if you are the administrator of website2, also check this other question.

[How to make cross domain request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request)