# XMLHttpRequest POST works on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, xmlhttprequest

I'm using XMLHttpRequest() to send an xml request to asp classic page. The same request returns the expected response (response = "Response received") when server.asp is on localhost, but not when it is on my godaddy website.

When I googled I found that it's because of crossdomain, but I couldn't find a solution for it.

I tried the same with $.ajax with same result.

Javascript:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://www.myserver.com/server.asp", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
xmlhttp.send("<xml/>");
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

server.asp

```
Response.Write ("Response received")
```

Comment: check this: [Using CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)

Comment: Kindly refer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request)