# Load image from other site by using jquery post?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to load image from other site by using query and replace it in div

```
MY HTML:
<div id="img_30"></div>
<div id="img_120"></div>
<div id="img_day"></div>
<div id="img_week"></div>
<div id="img_month"></div>
```

-

```
JQUERY:

var symbol = $("#stock").val();
symbol = symbol.concat('*BK')
$("#show_symbol").html(text_value);

$("#img_30").html( "<img src='dummy.png'>" );
$("#img_120").html( "<img src='dummy.png'>" );
$("#img_day").html( "<img src='dummy.png'>" );
$("#img_week").html( "<img src='dummy.png'>" );
$("#img_month").html( "<img src='dummy.png'>" );
```

site and parameters (example):

```
http://www.chartty.com/investorzChart.php?symbolnsources=symbol&period=Monthly&interval=1&Cycle=MONTH1
```

so my jQuery.post() it should be look like:

```
$.post( "http://www.chartty.com/investorzChart.php", 
{ symbolnsources: "symbolnsources", 
  period: "monthly",
  interval:"1",
  Cycle:"MONTH1",
 })
.done(function( data ) {
alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

or not.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't make cross-origin javascript requests. You have to make JSONP call...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make cross domain request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is being appended to the url you need a get request, also drop the additional comma at the end of your passed up data after Cylcle:

```
$.get("http://www.chartty.com/investorzChart.php", {
  symbolnsources: "symbolnsources", 
  period: "monthly",
  interval:"1",
  Cycle:"MONTH1"
}).done(function(data){
  //load the data into your site unfortunately the link provided is down so I can't see the data format returned
});
```

This answer is assuming CORS is enabled.