# Javascript: How to read data from remote js file?

Tags: javascript, remote-file-inclusion

I have a javascript file from remote server and it contains a variable which has data which I want to access.

**Js file:**

```
http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/3/d/itemjs
```

Js file contain code like below

```
var MyItemData={"counts":{"q":1,"a":1,"r":2,"ar":4,"rr":0,"dq":1,"da":1,"c":0,"sdsd":0},"active":true};
```

I've used below code but it's giving error for cross-origin request block.

```
var target = 'http://static.www.xxx.com/mydata/uXKojYEd9WXFpAasite/v4_3/3/d/itemjs';
jQuery.get(target, function(data) {
                                        alert(data);
                                    });
```

Any other way to get the data ?

Comment: Store it as JSON data and retrieve it.

Comment: If you have access to server code, set `Access-control-Allow-Origin` header to your ip or to `*`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make cross domain request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request)

Comment: @suzo That's useless since the remote file is JS, not JSON. It cannot be used as data.

Answer (score 1):

If the remote file is javascript and contains variable declaration as in your example, it will be available for other scripts on web page including your script. You only need to load this file as javascript and listen for its [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) event. When it fires you'll have access to that variable.

So the code might look like this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = target; 
script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // at this moment MyItemData variable is accessible as MyItemData or window.MyItemData
});
```