# Alert 200 when using jQuery JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have following codes. I used it to get some data from another domain address. In my local network. If anyone can tell me What I did mistake here or give me resolves.

```
<html>
  <title>Jquery Json</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
        type:"GET",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        crossDomain: true,
        //url: "http://10.1.128.107/JsonDohaBackToTemplate/getProjectIDByMAC.svc/media/?projectid=1",
        url: "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/415/?_=1357337284504", 
        success: function(data) {
          $("body").append(JSON.stringify(data));
        }, 
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(jqXHR.status);
        },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    });
  });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Another domain? You are not allowed, your probably get a security error right?

Comment: @putvande 
I've just use url: "http://fantasy.premierleague.com/web/api/elements/415/?_=1357337284504" for test. 
But when I used url: "http://10.1.128.107/JsonDohaBackToTemplate/getProjectIDByMAC.svc/media/?projectid=1", my domain also same error. It's is like an alert box displaying 200

Comment: It is a crossdomain policy, you can't connect to another domain via JavaScript.

Comment: How I get xml data from that address call 10.1.128.107...-> 
I need to get xml data from it and display it. My IP address is 10.1.128.103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is not allowed to load resources cross-domain. You need to look into Cross Origin Resource Sharing (cors). Check out these questions:

[Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

And of course wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: I need to get xml data from 10.1.128.107 IP address, And need to display it. How I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following from your call: async, cache, crossDomain, contentType, and error. These all not needed to make crossdomain call, but may be the reason why it's not working for you, because it looks like you have a usual call. E.g. error handler is never called for crossdomain

Here is what you need as minimum:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '',
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {     
                        },
                        dataType: 'jsonp'
                    });
```

UPDATE: Since you are getting XML, not jsonp, then you have only 2 choices:

1) Add following headers to your response, if you have access to server:

```
name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"
 name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"
```

2) Use server side proxy

Comment: Hi! I'm a new for this. Can you explain me one by one

Comment: Please see update. In order to crossdomain work, you need also server support. If you are receiving XML, jsonp will not work because jsonp requires server to return jsonp data type