# How to call ajax request with JSON response using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I cannot print success from the below code with the line **jQuery.support.cors = true;**. Including the line **jQuery.support.cors = true;** will give a warning message. So how can I avoid that without losing the functionality? My main objective is to call a rest web service that returns JSON data and I have to utilize the JSON data. Please help me with how I can achieve this. Please provide a working sample

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax ({
        url: 'http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json',
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            // Success callback
            alert("sucess");
        }})
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the option is `dataType` and not all lowercase but not sure how much of a difference that makes, if jquery can handle it or not, can't remember. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: "will give a warning message" Which message? Cross domain issue?

Comment: I assume this is a crossdomain ajax request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771
Try jsonp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You might missed to add **`type`**  //GET or POST, which type of REST OPEATION
2. **`dataType`** is mispelled
3. Missed to add **`contentType`**

---

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //rest Type
            dataType: 'jsonp', //mispelled
            url: "http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);                
            }
 });
```

**Updates:**
While trying to figure out the reason, I think this is the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584/1671639) to understand the problem.

> Say you're on domain abc.com, and you want to make a request to domain
>   xyz.com. To do so, you need to cross domain boundaries, a no-no in
>   most of browserland.
>
> The one item that bypasses this limitation is  tags. When you
>   use a script tag, the domain limitation is ignored, but under normal
>   circumstances, you can't really DO anything with the results, the
>   script just gets evaluated.
>
> **Enter `JSONP`.** When you make your request to a server that is JSONP
>   enabled, you pass a special parameter that tells the server a little
>   bit about your page. *That way, the server is able to nicely wrap up
>   its response in a way that your page can handle.*

Answer (score 3):

The best shot will be using a jsonp request. For this just specify `dataType` to be `jsonp`

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);        
    }
});
```

See example on [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/655jC/)

Comment: Voted up for fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) isn't the same as XSS.

`$.support.cors` contains the result of a test that tests whether or not the current browser supports cors. changing it doesn't make the browser support cors.

Also, your server has to support `CORS` by returning the proper headers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , it gives best results. This was used in REST Architecture, the response speed is very high

```
function CallService(sucessData) {
    $.ajax({
        // Add code for Cross Domain
        headers: getHeaders(),
        type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: varUrl, // Location of the service
        data: varData, //Data sent to server
        contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
        dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
        processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
        crossDomain: true,
        timeout: 200000,
        success: sucessData,
        error: function (xhr) {// When Service call fails
            alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are requesting *Cross-Domain* service, then you need to include **jQuery.support.cors = true;**. And the correct AJAX code would be:

```
 $.ajax ({
    url: 'http://json-cricket.appspot.com/score.json',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (jsonData) {
        // Success callback
        alert("sucess");
    },
    error: function() {
        //any error to be handled
    }
 });
```