# How to get only "steamid" from AJAX(or something idk)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've tried to only get "steamid" from AJAX(idk) link and I couldn't did it. Could you guys please help?

Link to find and get only "steamid" : [here](https://gamdom.com/user/%E2%9C%AA%20LocalRave%20Gamdom.com.json)

I've tried this code:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
 var ba =  this.responseText.split('\n'); var bubu = ba[ba.length-1]; console.log(ba); 
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://gamdom.com/user/%D0%BA%D1%94%CE%B7%CA%B8%E1%B5%98%E1%B6%A4%CB%A2%20gamdom.com.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Comment: please post your code and/or upload a fiddle

Comment: ok. did it.....

Comment: How about creating an object using `JSON.parse` and then accessing the wanted property?

Comment: I dont know anything. Could you please give me the code?

Comment: You might also have a cross-origin probelm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.

```
fetch('https://gamdom.com/user/%E2%9C%AA%20LocalRave%20Gamdom.com.json').then((response) => response.json()).then((data) => console.log(data.user.steamid))
```

[image]

Comment: If the end-user isn't on the same domain as the request URL then they'll encounter a CORS error

Comment: Sure, but we can navigate to their domain and check the console right???

Comment: yeah, but if the OP was trying to use this code on their own server (ie not gamdom) then they'll encounter a CORS error like so: https://jsfiddle.net/ejs0byLc/3/

Comment: use jsonp if poosible..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980841/how-to-call-ajax-request-with-json-response-using-jquery

Comment: It worked. Thank you. How about getting someone's that we dont know his link. Like when the server sends new  Request Method: GET with https://gamdom.com/user/blablabla.json ?