# $.ajax JSON request fails even with valid JSON data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Here is my code:

```
var jsonURL = "http://www.sodexo.fi/ruokalistat/output/daily_json/440/2013/10/25/fi";

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: jsonURL,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET"
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
        alert(msg);
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
```

What am i doing wrong? Im getting only parsererror with this code. Thank you guys for helping.

Comment: As it seems cross domain ajax request so `dataType` should be `jsonp`.

Comment: this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery

Comment: Changing dataType to jsonp didn't do it. parsererror is still what i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the raw HTTP response using Fiddler I see:

```
3f6
{ /* what likes like JSON here */ }
0
```

i.e. looks like your server is putting random characters around the JSON block which may be what's upsetting the jQuery parser.

**edit**

If you can't get the server response to change, you could change the `dataType` to 'text' and parse it yourself if the format is consistent. Looking at it, I suspect the first line is the length of the message and the last line a terminator. Once you've stripped those chars just parse the JSON using `JSON.parse`

Comment: Is there anything i can do to this in client side?

Comment: Added suggestion for client-side workaround to answer