# working XML feed , blogger is an exception?

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bpBtC/1/

But this http://jsfiddle.net/bpBtC/131/ doesn't work with the same method?

(All the other websites with XML feeds also fail using the same method, why?)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2399953/posts/default",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
});

function xmlParser(xml) { 
    $(xml).find("entry").each(function () {
        $(".entirecont").append($(this).find('title').text());
    });
}
```

Comment: jsonp - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `dataType` twice.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2399953/posts/default",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: xmlParser,
        dataType: 'jsonp' //<-- this is what actually used.
    });
```

Remove the second dataType and your code will fail.http://jsfiddle.net/bpBtC/130/

Comment: Could you plz create another fiddle demonstating the issue with Tumblr?

Comment: Well, it seems that Thubler doesn't implement jsonp. The response is xml. While blogger response is wrapped with a callback. Open this link in browser tab http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2399953/posts/default?callback=cb

Comment: wowowoow !! great... didn't realize that callback wrap in blogger

Answer (score 0):

The first fiddle works because it is using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (not XML) as the return data type and a method of circumventing the cross-site scripting restrictions. Familiarize yourself with JSONP and how it works.

The second feed does NOT return JSONP, it returns XML and so it can't work. Also you can't have two datatype-parameters on same ajax-call.

Comment: blogger.com implemented jsonp so this is why it is working, the other sites you tried didn't.

Comment: According to Tumblr they have JSONP-enabled api http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2 It should work if called right.

Comment: Modified my answer why the second fiddle does not work. You are not calling the tumblr api correctly to get jsonp result.