# Getting txt from server that doesn't allow cross domain ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am trying to get a txt file from another server and load it to a div using jquery ajax.

```
$("#div1").load("www.serverA1d.com/demo_test.txt");
```

I get

> Origin http://www.mysiteA.com is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I don't have control over the serverA1d or the demo_test.txt.
How can I retrieve this txt file using ajax ?

Comment: You can't do this with ajax, you need some server side scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done, but it's problematic.  By default, servers and browsers don't allow this, due to security concerns.

Here's more on the concept of Cross-Domain AJAX calls...

[Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)

And, here are some ways you can potentially work around this...

[jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)