# Amazon S3: possible to get https?

Tags: ssl, amazon-s3

I need to host some javascript files on Amazon s3 and would like to serve it through the amazon s3 url not through my domain.com using https

https://my.website.s3.amazonaws.com/js/custom.js

Is this offered for free or do I need to buy a SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's free. Basically Amazon provides the certificate for https://*.s3.amazonaws.com  .  If you are using your own DNS entry https:// then you need your own certificate.

Keep in mind that you might have to make cross domain javascript requests unless all of your site goes to: `https://my.website.s3.amazonaws.com` .

To do cross domain Javascript you need to use JSONP. You can read more about it here: [Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)

Or you can look at something like [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/)

[Edit]

If for some reason your bucket has a dot or more in its name, for example: mybycket.is.great you can use the old style URL

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/admobius.qa/mybucket.is.great/<bucket object>
```

Comment: But... this is only usable on bucket names without dots... the wildcard cert is only good for one "level" of hostname... https:// for foo.s3.amazonaws.com works, but for foo.bar.s3.amazonaws.com doesn't... because the cert is not valid at additional hostname levels out.  The bucket works, but the cert won't.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that's right, check my [Edit] for a workaround

Comment: this is for a bookmarklet I'm creating I need to load some JS from an https protocol