# Connecting to W3Schools sample WebService via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services

I am trying to connect W3Schools sample webservice via jQuery Ajax but it's not working for me.

Here is the JS:

```
function ConnectToWebService() {
    var pdata = "Celsius:123";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        data:pdata,
        contentType: "application/text; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit",
        success: function (msg) {
            $('#divToBeWorkedOn').html(msg.d); 
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("could not connect to service");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the target site? It's currently throwing a .NET error.

Comment: I assume it's throwing an error because it expects you to POST stuff, not simply perform a GET. I may be wrong though.

Comment: what is ``$.mobile`` @Adil Waqar???

Comment: @JuannStrauss No, I performed a POST using the JSON supplied. There's a runtime error in the site. It's all moot though, as the client Javascript is broken: `$.mobile` is invalid (may be a jQuery Mobile object?).

Comment: its for mobile as i am developing phonegap app , but for now i have eliminated it

Comment: is it W3c sample service or W3Schools sample service ?

Comment: sorry my bad W3Schhols

Comment: @BenPoole yes its working i have check it twice after u said its throwing exception

Comment: it is cross domaina ajax call use jsonp see: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Answer (score 0):

The error on the page says $.mobile is undefined. Include the proper URL to where $.mobile is defined and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't work:

```
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = false;
```

If you take it off your javascript will work. Just so you know, I'm getting here that "could not connect to service".

Next time insert some logs or alerts in your code to debug. I just put one before and one after the line that was not working to see if the ajax request was being sent and saw that this line was the problem.

(In chrome <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> opens debug window, open console and you can see js logs (console.log). A lot better than alert for debug)

Ps: For cross domain ajax call use jsonp, as Ehsan Sajjad commented:

- [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)
- [Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery)

Ps2: I never used this, but it might be useful: [Cross-origin Ajax](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/)