# how to solve cross domain in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to solve my AJAX cross domain problem. This is the error message I receive in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://'myaddress'/TEST/user/login/testuserid . Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

this is my source code

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain : true,
    dataType : "json",
    url: fullUrl,
    method: method,
    headers:headers,
    data: body,
    success: function(data, state, res){
        if (data == null)
            data = '';

        console.log( '[[[[[[[[SUCCESS!!]]]]]]]   url: ' + url + ',   state:' + state + ',   data : ' + JSON.stringify( data ) );
        callback(data, state, res);
    },
    error: function(data, state){
        if ( data == null )
            data = '';

        console.log( '[[[[[[[[[ERROR!!]]]]]]]]]   url: ' + url + ', s  tate:' + state + ',   data : ' + JSON.stringify( data ) );
        callback(data, state, null);
    }
});
```

Servlet code for cross Domain

```
httpRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
httpRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
httpRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

Comment: Have you inspected the response in your browser to see if the headers are actually set?

Comment: did you try `httpRes.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `JSONP` to make `CROSS DOMAIN Requests`.

Please read:

[Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-jquery-ajax/17299796#17299796)

[Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery)

Comment: JSONP is not a definitive requirement. It's just one option.