# How to Parse RSS urls from an external server or site from where the feed is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, json, rss, atom-feed

I use a [plugin](https://github.com/sdepold/jquery-rss) to parse rss feeds to my site   the HTML mark up is below.

```
<body>
script src="lib/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/jquery.rss.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $("#rss-feeds").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/premiumpixels")
  })
</script>
</head>
 <body>
     <div id="rss-feeds"></div>
```

My question is, how can I place the rss url on a another site or server and parse it to my site via JSON?

basically I need to know how to Parse rss urls on my site with the url feeds coming from an external site or server via JSON.

Comment: use YQL's feed data source to convert the RSS into JSONp

Comment: Check [Superfeedr's Feed API](https://superfeedr.com)

Comment: interesting, looks a bit complex so i'm not sure yet if it will suit my needs, thank you. @JulienGenestoux

Comment: Also check out [RSS to API](https://github.com/csm123/RSStoAPI), which provides an API through which your JavaScript can consume RSS, getting around cross-origin restrictions. Easy to deploy. I'm the author

Answer (score 0):

You may have difficulty doing cross origin requests if the external site is not controlled by you.  The external server will have to have CORS enabled.

Read about it here:
[Make cross-domain ajax JSONP request with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)