# Bad request error while posting from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi am trying to pass data through ajax and getting Bad request error any help please

```
 $scope.getSubCategory = function(id)
       {
           var category_id=id;
            var data = {"CategoryId":"2"};
           $.ajax({
                    url: "http://cashobby.abhigna.info/Services/CashobbyService.svc/subCategory",
                    type: "POST",
                    crossDomain : true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:data,
                    success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data);

                    },
                    //if wrong otp shoe user a error message

                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        // alert(request.responseText);
                    }
                });
       }
```

please check the error[image]

any help please I have tried to pass data `'{"CategoryId":"2"}';` and through `JSON.strinify` but no help any suggestion

Comment: `dataType: "jsonp",` consider adding a `p` while cross domain requests.

Comment: Can you show us the full error?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671317/400-bad-request-http-error-code-meaning

Answer (score 0):

try adding `contentType` to your ajax body as

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: are you posting to Cross Domain ? Consider reading this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Maddy it helped in my case so i shared. But thanks for the info

Comment: veer G, @ShaminderSAujla you have to explain properly when you answering.

Comment: Ok bai G, will take care next time.