# Can't make a XMLHTTPRequest (Cross-site)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make a XMLHttpRequest to a server, the server accepts JSON as arguments and it's supposed to register the arguments I'm sending.
Here's my code:

```
function makeXMLRequest() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://mywebserverhere/register", true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.status != 200)  {
            // Error
        return;
        }
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlhttp.send({"name": "pedro21", "pass": "nAosei1"});
}
```

But I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mywebserverhere/register. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: CORS headers come from the **server**, not the client. Adding those headers to the request has no effect at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

To allow CORS in a POST request you need to make a header. With GET you don't must to put this, but with POST you need:

```
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('X-PINGOTHER', 'pingpong');
```