# How to load file with jquery from different domain

Tags: jquery

I have a website on two domains.  I want to load a file what is on a different server.

When I load it like this (same server) it works perfect

```
$("#prijslijst1").load("info_prijs_vd.html");
```

however when I try this

```
$("#prijslijst1").load("www.example.com/info_prijs_vd.html");
```

it doesn't load. I've tried also http://www.example.com  etc.
I can't figure it out what's wrong here.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".  Also, you need to use a full url - `http://www.example.com/info_prijs_vd.html`.  BUT, you are also likely going to have to deal with [CORS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)

Comment: do you have permission to do a cross request to that domain?

Comment: If you do run into CORS issues you can always use https://crossorigin.me

Comment: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I don't know actually. I testing on a raspberry singleboard computer. With Apache2 with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

As this post perfectly exposes [Loading cross domain endpoint with jQuery AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005500/loading-cross-domain-html-page-with-ajax)

You are running into a CORS issue.

You need to follow the steps in the post I described, in order to solve your issue.

Cheers!