# Consume Restful request JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, rest

When I test the code below it only fails

Any Ideas? The link works fine

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://ulacit3352.cloudapp.net/Login/webresources/generic/search/gera',
  type: 'GET',
  datatype: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    alert("works")
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("it does not");
  }
});
```

[I get this on Chrome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnUlO.png)

Comment: When you say fails, can you describe more? What fails? Are you getting some error?

Comment: On the script I´m only testing, Instead of getting the success message I only get the message of the error.Thanks

Comment: Implement proper error handling - show the error, look in the console. You likely get access denied due to CORS issues - you cannot run the above from a file on your computer and you cannot run it from another domain

Comment: are you calling this URL outside from cloudapp.net?

Comment: Yes I am, I am testing it with postman and it gives me the correct respond

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11736771/6426617 check this answer

Comment: probably you are getting a `CORS` error. try to set the `allow-origin` on header.

Answer (score 1):

The response of the link is not of type "json", instead, it is a plain text, therefore it cannot be parsed. You should change to

```
dataType: 'text',
```

Also, for normal ajax, you need to make sure the url is in the same domain of the webpage, which means the code should reside at `http://ulacit3352.cloudapp.net/` as well. Otherwise, you should seek for "jsonp" or (better) some server-side solution, such as setting `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` or make your server as a proxy of the request.

Comment: Thank you for that, but it stills go to the error path

Comment: The thing is that if I test it with the localhost url it doesn´t work either

Answer (score 0):

The requested url is server on `http` which will give rise to `This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS` error since the connection is open for eavesdropping and man-in-the-middle (MITM) attacks. It is better to use `https` provided the url accept `https` request.

Still there is way to bypass the issue. You can check this [**LINK**](https://pearsonnacommunity.force.com/support/s/article/ka6d00000019KVGAA2/How-to-display-mixed-content-with-Google-Chrome-Internet-Explorer-or-Firefox-1408394589290)

Comment: Thanks I will try that