# ajax url is not working to server and localhost

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, post, get

I'm writing code with jquery. The code is not working to localhost and server.

```
    $.post("http://www.example",function(reply){

alert(23);

        });
```

The same problem applies to the get, ajax functions.

I tried it with ajax. It happened.
The Ajax command does not work at all.
url wants to attract information from different site.
Could this be the reason for not working?

---

my problem is still going on.
I am no getting its data. The code I wrote is below.

```
var url="http://example.comm?city=london";//this site is get the data I sent. it return as text.

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:"get",
        dataType:"jsonp",
        jsonp:"callback",
        success:function(value){

    $("#abc").text(value);
        },
        error:function(reply){
        alert(reply);//alert reslut:"<object></object>"

        },


    });
```

Comment: For  jQuery >= 1.6 , try using `.fail(function(data) { console.log(data); });` chained to your post and check for errors

Comment: Please define _The code is not working_. And also have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)?

Comment: my problem is still going on.
I am no getting its data. I've added up the codes.