# Send JSON using $.Ajax() with a POST method

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to send a JSON object using $.ajax() in jquery with a POST method, from my pure html page ,to a datapower endpoint.the response header in fire bug gives me"internal server error",please can any one tell me what i am doing wrong here :
HTTP/1.1 500 Error
X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL
Content-Type: text/xml
Connection: close

My Jquery code looks like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn_submitcallback').click(function () {

                //add the values we need for the API to an object
                var objCallbackData = new Object;
                var d = new Date();
                var dat = d.getDate();
                var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;
                var year = d.getFullYear();
                var todayDate = dat + "/" + mon + "/" + year;
                alert("inside submit callback");
                //build the object
                objCallbackData.Store_Code = "POO726"; //$('#sel_title').val();
                objCallbackData.Title = $('#sel_title').val();
                objCallbackData.First_Name = $('#txt_firstname').val();
                objCallbackData.Last_Name = $('#txt_surname').val();
                objCallbackData.House_Number = $('#txt_houseno').val();
                objCallbackData.Street = $('#txt_streetname').val();
                objCallbackData.City = $('#txt_city').val();
                objCallbackData.Post_Code = $('#txt_postcode').val();
                objCallbackData.Email = $('#txt_email').val();
                objCallbackData.Phone_Number = $('#txt_phone').val();
                objCallbackData.Project_Type = "Bathroom";
                objCallbackData.Callbacktime_Morning = "Y";
                objCallbackData.Callbacktime_Afternoon = "Y";
                objCallbackData.Callbacktime_Evening = "N";
                objCallbackData.Callbacktime_Weekend = "N";
                objCallbackData.Callbacktime_Weekday = "Y";
                objCallbackData.Helparea_Measuring = "Y";
                objCallbackData.Helparea_Designing = "N";
                objCallbackData.Helparea_Usingspaces = "N";
                objCallbackData.Helparea_Services = "N";
                objCallbackData.Helparea_Productinfo = "N";
                objCallbackData.Status = "O";
                objCallbackData.Date = todayDate;

                // alert(objCallbackData.date);


                //turn the object in to a JSON string
                var myJson = JSON.stringify(objCallbackData);
                alert(myJson);


                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://xb629050-s1.uk.b-and-q.com:9340/api/callback',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: myJson,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function () {
                        alert("good");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status) {
                        switch (status) {
                            case 404:
                                alert('File not found');
                                break;
                            case 500:
                                alert('Server error');
                                break;
                            case 0:
                                alert('Request aborted');
                                break;
                            default:
                                alert('Unknown error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                        }
                    }
                });


            });
        });
```

Comment: try removing the `charset` from `contentType`

Comment: Tried removing the charset ..no joy!!:(

Answer (score 0):

Ajax does not support cross domain request.
You need to use jsonp method for this.

Also see this

[How to make cross domain ajax call using jQuery JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348295/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-call-using-jquery-jsonp)

Comment: Tried the ajax shortcut $.post() in jquery ,the data is reaching the endpoint but not as JSON .Any idea how i can force the content-type of $.post() method ,since $.ajax() is not working ?

Comment: @user2301878 `$.post` is a convenience method of `$.ajax`. If it can't be done with `$.ajax` it can't be done with `$.post`. Not saying you can't do what you want... just saying `$.post` won't help

Answer (score 0):

@Thrustmaster is right you cannot use POST-request for cross-domain asynchronous operation need to use GET because under the hood will load script-tag content.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://xb629050-s1.uk.b-and-q.com:9340/api?callback=?", 
    objCallbackData, processServerResponse);
```

where processServerResponse is function that will be called after getting data:

```
function processServerResponse(data) {
// processing data from server
}
```

Please see for example 'free geoIP'-service. Try to browse: http://freegeoip.net/json/?callback=handleResponse

PS some excerpt from wiki:

> .. a web page served from server1.example.com cannot normally connect
>   to or communicate with a server other than server1.example.com. A few
>   exceptions include the HTML  element. Exploiting the open
>   policy for  elements, some pages use them to retrieve
>   JavaScript code that operates on dynamically generated JSON-formatted
>   data from other origins. This usage pattern is known as JSONP.
>   Requests for JSONP retrieve not JSON, but arbitrary JavaScript code.
>   They are evaluated by the JavaScript interpreter, not parsed by a JSON
>   parser.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @vladimir77.Using your method described above, the datapower is getting a regular form submission using an HTTP GET  like this : But my datapower endpoint expects data in JSON format with a HTTP POST .Uisng your menthod the datasent over to datapower is not of JSON format

Comment: Thanks for the reply @vladimir77.Using your method described above, the datapower is getting a regular form submission using an HTTP GET                          
But my datapower endpoint expects data in JSON format with a HTTP POST .Sorry but i am a JQuery newbie.please could you suggest somthing that could help me sending data from my Jquery UI in JSON format with HTTP POST ..

Comment: You are welcome :) @user2301878 the main concern is you sent async request to another domain, isnt it? jquery (and any another client library) is a tool that cannot break cross-domain restrictions because browsers prohibit that submission. May be you try to make cross-domain request through server (using WCF for instance or WebRequest) - you send POST-request to your server and it propagate its to datapower endpoint?