# calling web service using $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

i am trying to call a web service using simple $.ajax 
i have been trying to do this for long time but all samples and answers are not working for me
and anyone help with this

i am trying to call this url

http://ajaxtest.com.rws2.my-hosting-panel.com/api/values

the result of it is as follows

```
<ArrayOfusers xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/www.icl.com.sa.Models">
<users>
<id>1</id>
<pass>55</pass>
<uname>john</uname>
<utype>5</utype>
</users>
<users>
<id>2</id>
<pass>0</pass>
<uname>hammad</uname>
<utype>0</utype>
</users>
<users>
<id>3</id>
<pass>7</pass>
<uname>wojeiech</uname>
<utype>7</utype>
</users>
</ArrayOfusers>
```

can any one please try to call this web service

http://ajaxtest.com.rws2.my-hosting-panel.com/api/values

using simple index.Html file

i tried this million time but no luck

Thank you

Comment: The domain you are calling ajax request to the URLhttp://ajaxtest.com.rws2.my-hosting-panel.com/api/values is same domain or different?

Comment: it is a different domain

Comment: Cross domain ajax request are not allowed. You need to send request to the same domain and use curl or other thing on server side to request the webservice.

Comment: you could make a request to your server and in turn, let the server talk to that server.

Comment: i am trying to call it from a simple html web page that resides on my Desktop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make cross domain ajax call using jQuery JSONP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348295/how-to-make-cross-domain-ajax-call-using-jquery-jsonp)

Answer (score 0):

This is down to cross domain restrictions, which can prevent malicious code from running on the client side. If you have access to the web server and the API's code base, you could set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the domains that can execute the code, or even all domains with a value of `*`.

You could also investigate JSONP, but if the API doesn't support it then you won't be able to consume the data.